# How to display events for a day in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css, calendar

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gtxzom8s/

HTML:

```
<div id="dates"></div>
<div id="dateevent">
</div>
```

JS

```
var Event = function(text, className) {
    this.text = text;
    this.className = className;
};

var events = {};
events[new Date("02/14/2011")] = new Event("Valentines Day", "pink");
events[new Date("02/18/2011")] = new Event("Payday", "green");

console.dir(events);

$("#dates").datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
onSelect: function(date) {
    var events2 = events[date];
  alert(events2);
  //list the events in #dateeventDIV
},
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var event = events[date];
        if (event) {
            return [true, event.className, event.text];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
});
```

How can I modify the script so I can populate `dateevent` with the events for that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` parameter for the `onSelect` callback is a string not a Date object like the beforeShowDay callback. You can just create a Date object with the date parameter in the `onSelect` callback

```
var events2 = events[new Date(date)];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtxzom8s/3/

Note that object keys are strings, so if you pass a Date object as the key it will be converted to a string (`Fri Mar 18 2016 14:27:47 GMT-0400 (SA Western Standard Time)`)

Comment: What if there are more than one entry for the same day... https://jsfiddle.net/gtxzom8s/4/ Thanks.

Comment: Then you will have to find another way to store your events data, maybe each day will have an array of events `events[new Date("03/18/2016")] = [new Event("Payday", "green"), new Event("Leave Early", "green")]` . and then read it back appropriately

Comment: I will store them in one array it looks like and use Split to separate them. Thank you.